# How to redirect beta/* to /*?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7, web-config

I have site in private beta, and now I need to redirect from beta/* to /*.
How can be this done in ASP.NET MVC?

Thanks
* = everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to setup a wildcard route that will take any route with beta and send it to an action that will then redirect you to the correct url:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Beta",  // Route name
                "beta/{*url}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Beta", action = "Index", url= UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Then in the Beta controller do the redirect:

```
public ActionResult Index(string url)
{
   return Redirect("/" + url);
}
```

Comment: I can't use this, because wher url is beta/xyz I wan't to have it redirected to /xyz

Comment: @Santas - Forgot to add in the url parameter to that method, which will address your comment

Comment: Changed to
if (Request.QueryString.Count == 0)
                return RedirectPermanent("/" + url);
            else
                return RedirectPermanent("/" + url + "?" + Request.QueryString.ToString());

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to have the rewriting [handled by IIS](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) for you. The application shouldn't be "aware" if it is in beta mode or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by defining a new route and using an `IRouteHandler` to handle the redirect.

See Phil Haack's blog about this:  http://haacked.com/archive/2008/12/15/redirect-routes-and-other-fun-with-routing-and-lambdas.aspx